# Passing Picture from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, android-adapter

I have a grid view when i click an item inside the grid view and its going to another activity and view it there my code something like this :

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
        }
});
```

Activity which is im going to view

```
Intent i = getIntent(); 
// Selected image id
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("s");
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.moodpic[position]);
```

Comment: You didn't pass anything named `"s"`.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: i got an error null exception could not run the activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to get Extra with wrong key here `getInt("s")`.

Try this

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change with

```
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id" , 0);
```

instead this

```
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("s");
```

This is because you have put **"id**" as a key so whenever you are retrieving then that key must be same and by default the value of int is ***0***.

Answer (score 0):

First Convert Image into Byte Array and then pass into Intent and in next activity get byte array from Bundle and Convert into Image(Bitmap) and set into ImageView.

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-

```
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); You can use this also.
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

2) First Save image into SDCard and in next activity set this image into ImageView.

3) Pass Bitmap into Intent and get bitmap in next activity from bundle, but the problem is if your Bitmap/Image size is big at that time the image is not load in next activity.

Comment: you can use it with other options also

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend a different approach.
It's possible if you REALLY want to do it, but it costs a lot of memory and is also slow. It might not work if you have an older phone and a big bitmap. You could just pass it as an extra, for example

```
intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)
```

A Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you can put it in an extra. Likewise, a bundle has `putParcelable` f you want to pass it inbetween activities, I would store it in a file. That's more efficient, and less work for you. You can create private files in your data folder using MODE_PRIVATE that are not accessible to any other app.